# Postgresql Server on a Tablet?

Tags: android, ios, git, postgresql

I am currently working on a (commercial) logistics project. We build a (partially) automated storage system in which the goods are stored randomly (think of nano-amazon). The positions of the objects are stored on the main computer and we are at the moment implementing the offsite backup via WAL (any objections?). One of our problems is that we have to operate during a power blackout and we can't produce enough energy for our computers for the worst case duration of the blackout which could be several hours. [This probably will never happen as we are in Germany, but there are some regulations we need to fulfill].

So my idea is to use a tablet [cheaper than a laptop], send the WAL-files to it so that the user can access the data during the blackout. But so far, I have seen no server implementation for tablets (either android or ios). Isn't there any or did I just not find it?

But maybe I'm also moving into the wrong direction. The Database is rather small (<50000 objects in the warehouse with each < 1kb) and the information we need during blackout is just one table (object_id -> position_in_warehouse) so that I even think about writing this information into a file and using git to copy the changes to the tablet. We also only need to know which objects have been removed during the blackout so that this information can easily be migrated back to the original db.

Or do you have other ideas?

Comment: It might be possible to push changes from a postgres table to a remote SQLite DB via trigger + pl/pythin function. Or trigger + SQLite FDW. SQLite DB can be installed on a tablet.

Comment: Have you considered a UPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a port of Postgres to Android - to use WAL files you'd need a working server. Even if it was ported, then you can't ship WAL files from x86 server to Android tablet - master and slave have to be the same major version, OS and architecture.

You really should just periodically export your data from Postgres to a simple file (I'd recommend SQLite) and just download it from a server. I suppose your tablets use WiFi and this file would be like 10MB zip-compressed.

Alternatively you could use `rsync` to keep this file updated. Don't use `git` - it will keep all previous versions of this file on your tablet - it would grow rather fast.

Comment: Thanks! (can't upvote yet). Regarding git: I planned to use a simple text file to store the object locations. And in this case git is just storing the diffs and not the new text file. Or what did you want to say?

Comment: Yes it stores the diffs. But all of them. Evey single update. It would work, but it would be a waste of space in a tablet.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that rsync also only sends diffs. So I guess the easiest way for me is to use a cron job with an interval of some minutes that triggers the update of my text file and uses rsync to update the tablet.

Answer (score 4):

Does your time have any value to you? Discard the Android + PostgreSQL option right now.

Keep it simple. You can get a cheap laptop for practically nothing, especially second hand. Since you clearly don't care about it actually *working* as a backup option, that seems like a no-brainer. You can run a streaming replica with WAL archiving for fallback.

For your real fallback option, you're on the right track with writing out the data you require to a flat file and syncing just that. Remember to actually test it - you should actually use it occasionally and make sure it works.

BTW, for your WAL-streaming backups, I suggest [PgBarman](http://www.pgbarman.org/), which will manage retention and rotation for you. You should *also* do logical dumps, and *remember to test your backups*.

Comment: The backup hardware (tablet or laptop) will be a part of our product and I have the feeling that a full laptop is too large and somehow to powerful. I just want to show some simple values from a database (or a file) and a full blown laptop sounds like an overkill. But we are still developing the feature. If we decide not to use the tablet, we could even write the data to a USB-Stick and use the user's laptop. (But we of course force him to always have a charged laptop).

Comment: @Foo Developing the feature for the product? Eep. The way you were talking made it sound like you were dealing with a pesky impractical regulation for some in-house operation, not building something for others. I think that for a *product* the appropriate thing to do is almost certainly to have a tablet attached and regularly update an SQLite database with a copy of the crucial table.